# WebSphere config over ssh. Set Web Container max size

Tags: bash, ansible, websphere

I am running 9.0.0.11 WebSphere. To install a war file I go through GUI installer and on the last stage press View administrative scripting command for last action to see the command line syntax that I can use in my ansible-playbook.

I also need to `Servers -> Server types -> WebSphere application servers -> server -> Thread pool` and set `Web Container -> Maximum size = 1000`

How to do it over ssh or in ansible-playbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you will need to invoke wsadmin with scripting to get that done,
something like:

```
pools = AdminConfig.list('ThreadPool', AdminConfig.getid( '/Cell:Cell01/Node:Node01/Server:server1/')).split()
AdminConfig.modify(pools[10], '[[maximumSize "100"] [name "WebContainer"] [minimumSize "50"]')
AdminConfig.save()
```